# Can't add tag facebook-application

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

I asked some [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976692/get-access-to-photos-tags-on-facebook), it has tags [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook) and [permissions](/questions/tagged/permissions). I also try to add [facebook-application](/questions/tagged/facebook-application), but I can't. Why, when it was on list below Tags input field.

Comment: hmm, interesting. I tried adding it for you but I couldn't either

Comment: Is there an error of some kind? Or it's just you have the tag in the list and it disappear after validation?

Comment: There is no error or information.

Comment: If I were on the dev team, tagging `facebook` would result in a big boxing glove on a gigantic spring firing out from your monitor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got it: facebook-application is a synonym to facebook.

[image: Facebook Tag Information]

Comment: I think it shouldn't be synonyms.

Comment: @lord_t, why? On stackoverflow, what questions can you envisage that relate to facebook that *won't* inherently be about the api/sdk/developing an application. More importantly, **what benefit do you believe would be added to the site** by being permitted to tag `facebook` separately from `facebook-application`? =)

Comment: ok, I understand:)